# H2 - Split file option in server mode

Tags: ssl, encryption, split, h2

Using H2 database, is it possible to use the [split file option](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system_split) while in [(SSL) server mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) and using [encryption](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#file_encryption)? If so, how can I do it?

I created a split database using this JDBC string:

```
jdbc:h2:split:28:/g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
```

It is stated that a split database always needs the `:split` option afterwards, which seems true because I get errors about corrupted files when connecting with

```
jdbc:h2:ssl://g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length string" [50000-170] HY000/50000
```

But when I attach the appropriate option, another error follows:

```
jdbc:h2:split:ssl://g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do volume está incorreta"; "ssl://g:/db_split.h2.db" [90031-170] 90031/90031 (Error message localized in Portuguese - something like "The syntax for file name, folder name or volume label is incorrect")
```

Is there a way to make these options coexist? I am considering [AUTO_SERVER](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode), but it would be a lousy option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server mode, use:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/split:28:/g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
```

When using SSL:

```
jdbc:h2:ssl://localhost/split:28:/g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
```

For embedded mode, use:

```
jdbc:h2:split:28:/g:/db_split;CIPHER=AES
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it! You could put at least the TCP example in the official documentation, just my 2 cents! :)